# Change color in beamer theme

Tags: beamer, color

I'm preparing a presentation using the following beamer theme:

```
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
```

Is there any easy way to change the yellow color to cyan each time it is used in the theme? I have used Latex for some time but I have absolutely no idea how beamer works.

**Edit:** Here is a MWE. When I compile this, the title box is yellow, and that is the color I wanted to change to blue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
\title{My title}  
\author{My name}
\date{\today} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AnnArbor` defines the background color for titles (and similar) with:

```
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=yellow!85!orange}
```

(see `beamerthemeAnnArbor.sty`).

To change it into a kind of blue you can use something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=cyan}
\begin{document}
\title{My title}  
\author{My name}
\date{\today} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: cyan background instead of yellow]

Changing the foreground color is as easy, e.g., use

```
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=yellow,bg=cyan}
```

to get

[image: yellow text, cyan background]

See the [`beamer` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more information about `\setbeamercolor` and keys like `fg` and `bg`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is just what I needed! Is there any easy way to change the color of the text in the title box too?

Comment: @WildFeather See the extended answer. But please also have a look at the [`beamer` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much again, your answer is perfect! I will also take a look at the manual, but the length is discouraging and I needed a quick solution for today.

Answer (score 16):

> I am offline for the rest of the week. If somebody sees a mistake etc. -- just
> edit it.

1. I don't see any yellow color.
2. This is why a so-called **minimal working example** (MWE) is needed to avoid such problems.
3. Look for the file `beamercolorthemebeaver.sty` on your computer. Here are the colors defined. See below.

---

### `beamercolorthemebeaver.sty`

```
% Copyright 2004 by Madhusudan Singh <madhusudan.singh@gmail.com>
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.
\mode<presentation>

\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=darkred!80!gray}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=darkred!60!black,bg=gray!30!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=darkred!70!black,bg=gray!15!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=darkred!80!black,fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=darkred,bg=gray!5!white}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{fg=darkred,bg=gray!15!white}

\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{fg=darkred!10!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{fg=darkred!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=gray!10!white}

%\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=gray!60!white}

\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

\mode
<all>
```

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Changing the Colors

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{0,0,100}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{0,100,100}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{0,200,100}
\definecolor{myNewColorD}{RGB}{0,100,200}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = green}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB, fg = green}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorC, fg = green}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=myNewColorD, fg = green}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, I totally forgot to write a MWE. The yellow color was in the title in the first slide. Any suggestions about where I can find the .sty file?

Comment: Never mind, I found it, thank you very much again!

Comment: @WildFeather Maybe you want to share your solution.

Comment: I just added a MWE, and I managed to find the .sty file you mentioned using the method of the accepted answer for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144698/find-a-file-by-name-using-command-line). The comment by @Schweinebacke was just what I was looking for, and using your answer I managed to also change the colors of the bars. It looks fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `\definecolor{myNewColorD}{rgb}{0,100,200}` != `\definecolor{myNewColorD}{RGB}{0,100,200}`! As `rgb` can be used to specify values between `0` and `1` while `RGB` allows for values between `0` and `255`.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Thanks, that was/is a typo! Now corrected.